# Fixing my datastore admin?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backup, python-2.7

I have datastore admin enabled in one app and the backup system seems to work or at least it reports being launched as mapreduce jobs in the queue. Now I want to make that for my other app but the admin console fails when hitting the datastore admin link:

These are my settings from app.yaml:

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
- datastore_admin: on
- appstats: on
- admin_redirect: on
- deferred: on
```

What am I doing wrong? It works for one app and not the other. I have not enabled federated login so it should work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 187, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 236, in _LoadHandler
    __import__(cumulative_path)
ImportError: No module named datastore_admin
```

What should I do to enable datastore admin and the backup system there? It works for my other app and that is also python 2.7 / GAE.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `datastore_admin` was removed for Python 2.7. For more details:
http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/32db6e9e8e55a5c6?pli=1